# Plot frequency response in MATLAB with a log scale in x-axis

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, audio-recording, microphone

I am trying to capture the frequency response of a Shure SM57 mic using a sinesweep. A graph that I obtained using `freqz(data)` is as follows:

[image: Frequency Response of Shure SM57- Derived]

However, I am looking for more of a frequency response with a log scale in the x-axis as follows (in the documentation of Shure SM57)

[image: Frequency Response of Shure SM57- Original]

Any idea on how to do that exactly? Will it be just axis scaling?

Comment: `semilogx(x,y)` will plot with a log scale in the x-axis

Comment: How do we bring the data out of freqz? X-axis should be in log scale and Y-axis in dB scale.

Comment: Concerning the validity of your graphs: if you use a simple loudspeaker-microphone setting for your measurements, most of the peaks and valeys are typically determined by your loudspeaker instead of your SM57. Did you consider using a calibrated measuring microphone first to finally subtract the frequency response of the loudspeaker?

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger That's a good question. I have considered that but how would you get frequency response of the loudspeaker? Any suggestion on that? And I have always tried looking for how to get calibrated measuring mic. Any suggestion on that as well?

Comment: Use a measuring mic with guaranteed flat frequency response (e.g. B&K but there are also cheaper ones). Then put both mics at the same position e.g. 1m in front of the speaker. Then measure both mics. Finally, estimate Shure minus measuring mic, assuming that the latter represents the loundspeaker frequency response.

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger I appreciate your answer! but I don't think I will have access to any of the mics you described. Is there any other way like may be looking into the frequency response of the speaker? As I know those are again tested in anechoic chamber which may make it not suitable in case of room measurement.

Answer (score 1):

As an example you can get the frequency response from `freqz` by adding output arguments. When you call `freqz` with output arguments it doesn't create a plot. Then you can use `semilogx` and create the labels yourself.

Here's an example

```
fSample = 48e3;
[H, w] = freqz([1 2 1]);

Hdb = 20*log10(abs(H));
semilogx(w/pi*fSample/2, Hdb, '-r', 'LineWidth', 2);
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');

% Play with the labels to make them look like the original picture
a = gca;
t2 = a.XTick(1:(end-1))*2;
ticks = [a.XTick; [t2 0]];
a.XTick = ticks(1:(end-1));
a.XTickLabelMode = 'manual';
a.XTickLabels = genLabels(a.XTick);

grid on;
```

`genLabels` is defined as

```
function lbls = genLabels(ticks)
    lbls = cell(numel(ticks),1);
    for idx=1:numel(ticks)
        d = floor(log10(ticks(idx)));
        unit = floor(d/3);
        switch unit
            case 0
                unitLbl = '';
            case 1
                unitLbl = 'k';
            case 2
                unitLbl = 'M';
            case 3
                unitLbl = 'G';
            case 4
                unitLbl = 'T';
            otherwise
                error('Unsupported');
        end

        lbls{idx} = sprintf('%d%sHz', round(ticks(idx)/(10^(3*unit))), unitLbl);
    end
end
```

Output plot

Edit: I added the x axis scaling based on some predefined sampling rate to the example.

[image]

Comment: That's good enough! How about getting it to 0 Hz - 20 kHz? I am seeing these are all in rad/sample. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: `freqz` plots the frequency response assumption that the sampling rate of the data was 1Hz (1 sample/unit time). You could scale first parameter of semilogx `w/pi` by the sampling rate divided by 4. From the plot it looks like the sampling rate of the data was probably 48kHz, the maximum rate of the ShureSM57. So you could try `semilogx(w/pi*(48e3)/4, Hdb);`

Comment: Oops realized the math I gave was wrong. You need to divide by 2 not 4. So `semilogx(w/pi*(48e3)/2, Hdb);`